# When i download file programmatically from s3 bucket, It gives me error It looks like we don't support this file format

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When I download file from s3 bucket, I am using aws-sdk for that, it downloads the files but when i open that file it says `It looks like we don't support this file format`, here is my full code of it, can anyone please check my code and help me why image is doesn't open the image, my wholde code is in PHP, It looks like small error but doesn't working for me

```
$bucket = '*****';
    $keyname = '1560346461616.jpg';
    $s3 = new S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => '******',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '******',
            'secret' => '******',
        ],
    ]);
    $result = $s3->getObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
    ]);
    header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$keyname); 
    echo $result['Body'];
} catch (Exception $e) {   
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the content type of your .jpg file stored in s3. Ensure the metadata for this object says image/jpeg.I don't think it is related to the object you downloaded,maybe the download file was corrupted.